# Trying to make Streamlit wait for input before rerunning app

Tags: terminal, streamlit, openai-api

I am trying to create a game that allows users to respond to questions asked by a gpt powered source. I am currently using streamlit, but streamlit keeps rerunning the app without waiting for a response. I want streamlit to wait for the response/input before running through the rest of the code/rerunning completely. For some context, the source takes in their answer and uses that to ask more questions.

Right now what is happening is that streamlit keeps rerunning even when some fields are blank/haven’t been answered yet. I tried to fix the situation by making the answer textboxes forms, but that still didn’t work. I also tried using time() and a pause function to no avail.

For example, I want to have my user introduce themselves. So I call this function:

```
def run_intro_completion(self, game):
   with st.form(key=‘my_form2’):
      intro_dialogue = st.text_input(label=‘Introduce yourself’)
      submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label=‘Submit’)
   num_tokens = 0
   if submit_button:
      return (intro_dialogue, num_tokens, submit_button)
```

However, it keeps saying that my intro_dialogue variable is Nonetype, because streamlit continues the execution without waiting for the submit button tobe pressed/the intro field to be filled out. Do you have any advice for how to make streamlit operate like terminal, where it waits for my user’s response before moving on to the next parts of the code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit does not function like a terminal. When you put a widget in the script, Streamlit is going to blow right through it with the output being its default value. (In the case of a form, the widgets output won't be updated until the submit button is clicked so they will return their default values and the submit button will return False while the user fills in the information or interacts with the app elsewhere.)

Your function is going to just `return None` on any page load not resulting from the submit button click.

Wherever you call your function, you will need to check the value it returns to see how to proceed. So for instance (filling in the return your function has as-is):

```py
def run_intro_completion(self, game):
   with st.form(key=‘my_form2’):
      intro_dialogue = st.text_input(label=‘Introduce yourself’)
      submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label=‘Submit’)
   num_tokens = 0
   if submit_button:
      return (intro_dialogue, num_tokens, submit_button)
   # else:
   return None
```

Supposing you have your object stored in `st.session_state.my_state`

```py
state = st.session_state.my_state
result = state.run_intro_completion(my_game)
if result is not None:
   # Do processing
```

I don't know what the larger structure of your app is, so there may be other fundamental details that will need to be handled for it to appropriately handle the logical structure of Streamlit, which is to rerun the entire script top to bottom with every interaction. Make sure that any object you want to successively change or build upon is stored in `st.session_state` as I've hinted.

Comment: I see thank you! Do you know a good web dev framework in Python that would allow me to wait for the input without having to do all of this?

Comment: My primary frontend for Python is Streamlit because of the lesser amount of code it takes in general. Getting into which frameworks are "good" in some regard gets into the opinion territory that Stack Overflow tries to avoid. I recommend reading some [comparisons](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+frontend+comparison).

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your advice, when I said good, I meant do you know a python web dev framework that waits for inputs within a while loop. Something that operated similar to terminal.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about it but what i think is i will give you the hint here use form instead of these things and in form use key streamlit having form key and then use submit button that will sure resolve your problem here is the example code ok..!

```
with st.form(key='my_form_to_submit'):

submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')

if submit_button:

<Code that should only be run after submit button has been clicked>
```